# Is there any way to run command line statements via Javascript?

Tags: javascript, command-line

I want to execute command line statements via Javascript code. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Can you define "command line statements"?

Comment: Do you mean an operating system command line? If so use Node.js `OS module`

Comment: Say for example,I can invoke Perforce(P4V) application via command line. But I want that command line to run when I run my JS file. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: @MaxMastalerz Yes , even that would do

Comment: Where are you currently coding? You can't run command line statements from a browser :P

Comment: In what environment is the JavaScript executing? It's not possible to interact directly with a command prompt / shell from client-side JavaScript run in a browser. You'd need a server-side layer to mediate.

Comment: Not from withing regular Javascript in the browser.  Security restrictions will not let you execute anything in the native OS (for obvious security reasons).  You would need a locally installed browser plug-in to do something like that.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/commander

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks. I didn't know about this thing as I am new to this. I will try look into Node.js modules to achieve this.

Comment: @Karthik: Just for clarification: node runs server-side, so you either need to run the node-webserver locally on the machine you want to execute the commands on, or it won't help you. BTW, there's a very good reason Javascript has no access to the system.

Comment: @Robert Alright :) Thank you !